# Dual space of a finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed space with dual $V^*$. Then $V$ is finite dimensional if and only if $V^*$ is finite dimensional, and in fact $\dim{V} =\dim{V^*}$

I set up the proof as follows: since  $V$ is finite dimensional then $V$~$R^n$.

then $V^*$~$(R^n)^*$~$R^n$~$V$.

then $V^*$ is finite dimensional, and in fact $\dim{V} =\dim{V^*}$.
my proof is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof relies on the fact that $\mathbb (R^n)^*\cong \mathbb R^n$. However, proving that is exactly as hard as proving the general claim that for finite dimensional spaces $V^*\cong V$. And besides, you need to take care of the case where $V$ is infinite dimensional, which you did not do. In any case, because of the above, your answer should not be accepted as a correct proof, or at the very least not as an insightful one.